# access 2010 docmd.runSQL

Tags: sql

I am using ACCESS 2010 and trying to run a simple command in one of my form buttons `btnRemove_Click()` and for some reason it always returns an error `"Run-Time error '2342' A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement"`

my code is here...

```
Private Sub btnRemove_Click()

Dim srtSQL As String

StrSQL = "SELECT TblProduct.Product
                 , TblItem.Product_ID
                 , TblOrder.OrderID 
          FROM TblProduct 
          INNER JOIN (TblOrder 
                      INNER JOIN TblItem 
                      ON TblOrder.OrderID = TblItem.OrderID) 
          ON TblProduct.ProductID = TblItem.Product_ID 
          WHERE (((TblOrder.OrderID)=3));"
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL

Text62.SetFocus
Text62.Text = StrSQL

End Sub
```

the reason I want to run the `DoCmd.RunSQL` command as string is that later I will remove the `(TblOrder.OrderID)=3` by a field in my form and I can see many people using this command normally in there videos in YouTube and tutorials, but seriously I have no idea why does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late on this one. But the problem is `DoCmd.RunSQL` is for running Updates/Delete type SQL and not SELECT. You need to Open a Recordset to "use" the Data returned.